# Prove that$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{|\sin(n^2+5)|}=\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove the following limit:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{|\sin(n^2+5)|}=\infty$$

I don't know how to do it, because $\frac{1}{|\sin(n^2+5)|}$ is unbounded, even though $\sin(n^2+5)\ne0$ for every natural number $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 4):

$$
0 < |\sin(n^2+5)| < 1 ,
\\
\frac{1}{|\sin(n^2+5)|} > 1 ,
\\
\frac{n}{|\sin(n^2+5)|} > n .
$$